# Android - if i start the camera - assignment detected data race

Tags: android, camera, signals, sigabrt

When i start the camera with this Code:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
```

I get this error:

```
A/sp: sp<> assignment detected data race
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 23833 (RenderThread), pid 23705 (name.name)
```

Does anyone know what the error message means and how I can fix the problem?

Comment: What evidence do you have that this is coming from your app? Bear in mind that `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` might start any of hundreds of camera apps, depending on the user's device and what they have installed. Some of those will have bugs, and there is very little that you can do about that.

Comment: Oh well, okay. How can I change the code so that no other app is called by the method?

Comment: What do you mean by "no other app"? The choice of camera app is up to the user, not you.

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem. The above code is executed in my app by a button. the camera then opens and the error message appears.

Comment: Add `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` to your `Intent` and see if that helps. If not, my guess is that this is a bug in the particular camera app that you happen to be trying.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not solve the problem.